# An application of the Banach-Steinhaus theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'd like to prove the exercise below, and I have difficulty demonstrating the existence of the limit by using conditions (1) and (2). What is the dense set for? Do I have to find a sequence in the dense set with $x$ being its limit? Incidentally, $L(X,Y)$ denotes the space of bounded linear transformations from $X$ to $Y$. A n.v.s. is a normed vector space. Thank you.

> [image]

Comment: Could you please mention the book or the source from which you took the image ?

Comment: Sure. The book is *Real Analysis*, and its author is Fon-Che Liu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{T_n\}$ satisfies $(1)$ and $(2)$ on a dense subset $D$ of $X$. Taken any $y\in X$ for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $x\in D$ such that $\lVert x-y\rVert <\varepsilon$.

Since $\lim_{n\to +\infty} T_nx$ exists we get $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for every $m, n>N$ we have $\lVert T_mx-T_nx\rVert<\varepsilon$ so
$$
\lVert T_my-T_ny\rVert\leq\lVert T_my-T_mx\rVert+\lVert T_mx-T_nx\rVert +\lVert T_nx-T_ny\rVert\leq (2M+1)\varepsilon
$$
where $M=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\lVert T_n\rVert$ by $(2)$. But also $Y$ is a Banach space so $\lim_{n\to +\infty}T_ny$ exists.

Now if $\lim_{n\to +\infty}T_ny$ exists for every $y\in X$ then $(1)$ is trivial and $(2)$ descends directly from Banach-Steinhaus theorem.

Comment: Thank you. But I can't understand how you brought out $\ldots\leq(M+1)\epsilon$. Could you explain more, please?

Comment: OK, I see the trick. That involves linearity of those transformations. FYI, there might be a typo: $(2M+1)\epsilon$.

Comment: Yes, it was just a mistake

Comment: Anyway the fundamental idea is just to prove that $T_ny$ is a Cauchy sequence in order to use completeness of $Y$.