# Why is $\sup_{||x||=1}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} ||T_nx|| \leq \sup_{||x||=1}\lim \inf{n \rightarrow \infty} ||T_nx||$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, banach-spaces

As the title suggests, I am having difficulties understanding the inequality extracted from the following proof;

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If a sequence has a limit then it is equal to the $\liminf$. And since $||T_nx||\leq ||T_n||\cdot ||x||$ we also have $\liminf ||T_nx||\leq\liminf ||T_n||\cdot ||x||$.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that out

Comment: @WorseThanEinstein Is your question solved?

Comment: @QuantumSpace Yes, the least inequality is a known inequality so the proof is fully clear from my side.

Comment: @WorseThanEinstein Alright just checking. Maybe edit your question to make this clears to others :)

Comment: What book is that ?

Comment: @Physor I don't know actually I am afraid. I have a problem-sheet and I searched the answer here on MSE for the problem in this thread. I then found a thread here, where the OP instead had problems with 5.1.1 in the post above. The thread is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3636538/an-application-of-the-banach-steinhaus-theorem